# How to greet your workmates casually in Japanese IT field office?

Tags: greetings

How 30-50 year old Japanese male would say hello to another male colleague in same age in same organisational level in IT company? I'm looking for everyday based not formal way to communicate.

Comment: Tell us the reason why you posted this question. (1) Because it is necessary at the workplace where you actually work. (2) Because you want to know the conversation at the workplace that you don't know in order to introduce Japan or something like that.   If your answer is (1), do as Japanese colleagues do in your workplace.

Answer (score 2):

my colleagues always say おっす to me

Comment: Hi taikun, please expand on your answer in a manner that addresses the OP's question with fact. For example, why is it acceptable for おっす to be used in this setting and what leads you to believe this?

Answer (score 2):

おはようございます and お疲れ様です are still the most common choices. But the actual pronunciation can be heavily slurred depending on the politeness level, and it may sound to you almost like "おやざーっす", "おつかさーっす" or even "おわーっす". After all, you say it every day, and everyone can understand what has been said.

おっす is usually used between close friends outside the office. It may be acceptable depending on the atmosphere of your office, but you should not be the first to start using this.

Comment: Another common method of saying お早うございます, is by letting the first part be silent and only say something like ざぃます.